# Clicking the button with Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying to write python code that clicks the "accept the cookies" button, but it doesn't work. I could not understand the problem. Can you help me? Here is my code:

Note: I am using MS Visual code, and

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/")
driver.maximize_window()

driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "flex--item6 s-btn s-btn__primary js-accept-cookies js-consent-banner-hide").click()
```

My goal is automatic clicking the accept the cookies button, but the code that I run has problem, and I did not understand the problem.

The HTML of the button is:

```html
<button 
   class="flex--item6 s-btn s-btn__primary js-accept-cookies js-consent-banner-hide">
    Accept all cookies
</button>
```

How can add HTML of the button? Was my way wrong?

I also added implicity wait like this: driver.implicitly_wait(15) but it doesn't click still.

Comment: What is the error that being thrown? I believe it might be a synchronization issue which means you need to use some sort of implicit wait or an explicit wait. Might be also an iframe tag in the "Accept cookies" pop up.

Comment: When I try with XPath, and as you said when I add implicit wait, it's  works. Thanks for your comment as well

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**I would recommend the following.**

1. Try using some different element selector such as`By.XPATH`(copy as full xpath) , `By.ID`, `By.CSS_SELECTOR`
2. Try using sleep methods as you don't want to happen the whole process so quickly.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/")
time.sleep(1)
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[4]/div[1]/button[1]').click() #full XPATH
time.sleep(5)
```

I hope this would help.

Comment: Using sleeps are a bad practice. You should instead use `WebDriverWait`. Also, any XPath that starts from `/html` or has a lot of levels and/or multiple indices are a bad practice/very brittle. A better locator would be a CSS selector, `button.js-accept-cookies`.

Answer (score 1):

To click on the element <kbd>Accept all cookies</kbd> within the Stack Overflow [homepage](https://stackoverflow.com/) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/")
  driver.maximize_window()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.js-accept-cookies"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/")
  driver.maximize_window()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(., 'Accept all cookies')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) Python solution that goes to this page and clicks the button.

```py
from seleniumbase import BaseCase
BaseCase.main(__name__, __file__)

class RecorderTest(BaseCase):
    def test_recording(self):
        self.open("https://stackoverflow.com/q/75652543/7058266")
        self.click('button:contains("Accept all cookies")')
        self.sleep(3)
```

(Note that standard CSS doesn't have the `:contains()` selector. That is unique to SeleniumBase and jQuery.)

The [SeleniumBase Recorder](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/help_docs/recorder_mode.md) was used to generate this script in a few seconds.